# Работа цикла while в работе

Tags: python

Имеется код

```
print("Введите исходные данные")
print("x0 = ", end='')
x0 = float(input())
print("hx = ", end='')
hx = float(input())
print("xn = ", end='')
xn = float(input())

print("Вы ввели:")
print("x0 = %.1f  xs = %.1f  x2 = %.31f" % (x0, hx , xn))
x = x0
y = 0
n=int(1)
round(n)
while x <= xn + hx/2:
    if x >= -2 and x <= -1:
       y = (2*x + 4)
    elif x > -1 and x <= 1:
       y = (x**2)*2
    elif x > 1 and x <= 2:
       y = -2*x + 2
    else:
       y = ("Error")


print("x = %.1f  y = %.1f" % (x,y))
x += hx
```

И почему-то он не работает так,как нужно.Объясните пожалуйста дураку,в чем дело.

Comment: Объясните сначала умным, что нужно, что происходит, и чем эти две вещи отличаются.

Comment: Собственно в чем дело.При вводе всех значений значение y стабильно остается равным 0.А хотелось бы,чтобы он менялся,как у меня в коде.Но я что-то сделал не так,а что - не понимаю.

Comment: а точно нужно именно такое условие: while x == x0 ?

Comment: А входные данные мы должны угадать?

Comment: Вроде как да.Но я мог и в условии ошибиться,ибо,по-сути,это мой первый опыт в языке python,и я еще не особо разбираюсь,что к чему :)

Comment: Так,всё прогрузилось,всё прочитал,прошу прощения:) Входные данные вводятся самостоятельно,но,как пример,x0 = 2, xs = 1, x2 = 1.И,как выяснилось,я скопировал старый код,тоже прош прощение,что ввёл в заблуждение.Отредачил вопрос и вставил новый код

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как сейчас говорят в России: "Отступы в Питоне - такие отступы."

```
print("Введите исходные данные")
print("x0 = ", end='')
x0 = float(input())
print("xs = ", end='')
xs = float(input())
print("x2 = ", end='')
x2 = float(input())
print("Вы ввели:")
print("x0 = %.1f  xs = %.1f  x2 = %.31f" % (x0, xs, x2))
x = x0
y = 0
while x <= x2 + xs / 2:
    if x >= -2 and x <= -1:
        y = (2*x + 4)
    elif x > -1 and x <= 1:
        y = (x**2)*2
    elif x > 1 and x <= 2:
        y = -2*x + 2
    elif x < -2 or x > 2:
        y = ("Error")
    print("x = ", x, "y = ", y)
    x += xs
```

Входные данные:

```
-3
0.25
3
```

Выходные данные:

```
x =  -3.0 y =  Error                                                                                                    
x =  -2.75 y =  Error                                                                                                   
x =  -2.5 y =  Error                                                                                                    
x =  -2.25 y =  Error                                                                                                   
x =  -2.0 y =  0.0                                                                                                      
x =  -1.75 y =  0.5                                                                                                     
x =  -1.5 y =  1.0                                                                                                      
x =  -1.25 y =  1.5                                                                                                     
x =  -1.0 y =  2.0                                                                                                      
x =  -0.75 y =  1.125                                                                                                   
x =  -0.5 y =  0.5 
x =  -0.25 y =  0.125                                                                                                   
x =  0.0 y =  0.0                                                                                                       
x =  0.25 y =  0.125                                                                                                    
x =  0.5 y =  0.5                                                                                                       
x =  0.75 y =  1.125                                                                                                    
x =  1.0 y =  2.0                                                                                                       
x =  1.25 y =  -0.5                                                                                                     
x =  1.5 y =  -1.0                                                                                                      
x =  1.75 y =  -1.5                                                                                                     
x =  2.0 y =  -2.0                                                                                                      
x =  2.25 y =  Error                                                                                                    
x =  2.5 y =  Error                                                                                                     
x =  2.75 y =  Error                                                                                                    
x =  3.0 y =  Error
```