# Определите координату точки,которая ближе расположена к началу координат

Tags: python

Имеется код

```
from math import *
print("Введите исходные данные")
print("x0 = ", end='')
x0 = float(input())
print("xs = ", end='')
xs = float(input())
print("x2 = ", end='')
x2 = float(input())
print("Вы ввели:")
print("x0 = %.1f  xs = %.1f  x2 = %.31f" % (x0, xs, x2))
x = x0
y = 0
while x <= x2 + xs / 2:
    y = 2*sin((3/4) * x)
else:
    y = ("error")
print("x = ", x, "y = ", y)
x += xs
```

Задача: Определить координаты точки (x, f(x), которая ближе всего расположена к началу координат, т.е. к точке (0, 0).

Проблема: У меня не вычисляются значения функции 2*sin((3/4)*x), но пишет error, в случае несоблюдения заданных условий. +Я не понимаю как определить координаты этой точки. Помогите пожалуйста :)

Comment: Что за три икса? Для чего while?

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1107604/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0-while-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5

Comment: Добрый день,Игорь! Делал сие по вашему образцу,но что-то упустил,и sin от заданного значения не вычисляется.Объясните дураку в чем дело :)

Comment: While - как необходимое условие лабораторки, x0 и x2 - начальные и конечные координаты. xs - шаг

Comment: Объясняю. Слева от моего ответа есть значок "галочка" ("птичка"). Он сделан для Вас. Пользуйтесь.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что питоновский `while` сочетается с `else`.

Comment: Очень хорошо. Спасибо. Мы продвигаемся вперед семимильными шагами.

Comment: Галочку поставил,сейчас исправлю else,а как определить эти координаты?

Comment: @Igor else после while выполняется, когда условие в while ставновится неверным.

Comment: @Эникейщик А-а-а, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = x0
y = 2 * sin(0.75 * x)
d2 = x**2 + y**2
xmin = x
ymin = y
while x <= x2 + xs / 2:
    y = 2 * sin(0.75 * x)
    if (x**2 + y**2) < d2:
        d2 = x**2 + y**2
        xmin = x
        ymin = y
    x += xs
print("x = ", xmin, "y = ", ymin)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо.А теперь объясните пожалуйсто,что тут написано,дабы в следующий раз,встретив аналогичное задание,я не писал сюда :)

Comment: @ВиталийАвечкин Нет уж. Сначала Вы скажите, что Вам здесь непонятно.

Comment: Хорошо.Что значит d2?

Comment: Остальное я всё,вроде,понял

Comment: @ВиталийАвечкин Это переменная, ее значение квадрат минимального расстояния до начала координат.

Comment: Так.Я запутался.Определить координаты точки (x, f(x)), которая ближе всего расположена к началу координат, т.е. к точке (0, 0).Это задание.
По итогу я получаю минимальное значение y при введенных точках,если я не ошибаюсь??

Comment: @ВиталийАвечкин Вы опять не рассказываете, что Вы делаете. Какие у Вас входные данные?

Comment: я брал x0 = 3, xs = 2, x2 = 1 
Предполагаю,что опять сделал что-то не так.

Comment: Предполагаете правильно. Вы понимаете, что у Вас за цикл?

Comment: Если честно,не особо.Объясните,пожалуйста

Comment: Цикл идет от `x0` до `x2` с шагом `xs`. Для каждого значения вычисляет `y`. Среди точек с координатами `(x,y)` находит ту, которая ближе всего к `(0,0)`.

Comment: То есть на интервале от 1 до 3,например, с шагом 0.5,на выходе я получаю y = ближайшему к (0,0) значению?

Comment: "я получаю y = ближайшему к (0,0) значению" - это по-русски? Нарисуйте график функции на Вашем интервале, поставьте на графике Ваши точки. Посмотрите, какая из них ближе всего к началу координат.

Comment: Согласен,написал черт знает что :)
Понял,спасибо.Сейчас нарисую,посмотрю